# Getting different Results in SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP with Mysqli and I'm trying to avoid duplicated results from the Database. However, the count result is different from these two very similar code. I'ts the first time I'm using DISTINCT, so I would like to know what's causing the difference. Thank you!

Ps: I saw similar question but the sql command is different.

Count: 83

```
SELECT DISTINCT (`email`) `id`,`name`,`email`,`sent`,`datasent` 
FROM $dbtable_requests 
WHERE `datasent`>'$datedb' 
  AND category = '$cat'  
ORDER BY `name`
```

Count: 77

```
SELECT DISTINCT (`email`) `id` 
FROM $dbtable_requests 
WHERE `datasent`>'$datedb' 
  AND category='$cat_q'
```

Comment: So whats in `$cat` and `$cat_q` as the variable names are different, are the contents also different?

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: have you tried with GROUP BY

Comment: they are in different functions that's why the $cat and $cat_q

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks I will take a look.

Comment: @Csimpi, I will try here